# Catching element by ID when it's defined with twig

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, getelementbyid

I've created some elements with php in order to made up a form. This is the snippet of PHP code:

```
$builder->add('path', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Submit', 'attr' => array('class' => 'style-1 btn_upload_pdf_php js-btn_upload_pdf', 'id' => 'pdf')));


$builder->add('title', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Flyer\'s name', 'attr' => array('class' => 'style-1 name_pdf js-name_pdf', 'placeholder' => 'Nome del volantino')));


$builder->add('expirationData', DateType::class,  array('label' => 'scadenza', 'attr' => array('class' => 'style-1 deadline_pdf js-deadline_pdf', 'placeholder' => 'Nome del volantino', 'id' => 'deadline_pdf')));
```

I've tried to set path's ID by twig with the following statement:

```
{{ form_widget(form1.path, { 'id': 'pdf'}) }}
```

But when I try to get element `($('#pdf'))` via JavaScript, it doesn't work. It seems that the element isn't created. 
Thx.

Comment: JavaScript code is the following snippet:
$('.btn_upload_pdf').click(function (e) {
        $("#pdf").trigger('click');
    });
Where the class "btn_upload_pdf" is referred to a button created via HTML. Furthermore, .click action is fired because if I insert an alert into it, it works.

Answer (score 1):

to pass id to twig form, you have to do it like that :

```
{{ form_widget(form1.path, {'attr': {'id': 'pdf'}}) }}
```